# VS Code automatic npm build fails with "npm command not found"

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

According to [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) it is supposed to work. When I press Ctrl-Shift-B, I do get `npm: build` as an option, which if I run I get `npm command not found` in the terminal. However, manually running `npm run build` works.

I am using `nvm`. Some relevant outputs:

```sh
 ~  which node
/home/gt/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
 ~  which npm 
/home/gt/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm
 ~  echo $NODE_PATH
/home/gt/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
```

What could be the reason for this? And how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the default tasks? or did you create a `tasks.json`?

Comment: I did not create a `tasks.json`, but according to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), straight up `ctrl shift b` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answering because I finally found the two things I needed to do:

1. Create a tasks.json as explained in [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551083):

   ```
   {
       "version": "2.0.0",
       "tasks": [
           {
               "label": "npm:build",
               "type": "shell",
               "group": { "kind": "build", "isDefault": true },
               "command": "/home/gt/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm run build"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   After this I got another error saying: `"/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory"`
2. Then I found this [github thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911), and so I created symlink as per suggestion:

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /home/gt/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node /usr/bin/node
   ```

and the `ctrl+shift+b` shortcut works now. Note that the source argument in your case can be got from `which node`.

Comment: Have you tried it without the `tasks.json` file? My guess is that if it was a path issue, it got resolved by the symlink anyway. For future, you can use `which node` inside the `ln` command. `ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node`

Comment: @technogeek1995 Hey, thanks but it doesn't work without the `tasks.json` file, instead says `npm` command not found.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely because npm isn't in VS Code's path (likely `/usr/bin`). However, you can create a custom build task and specify the path. In the `.vscode` directory, create a `tasks.json` file. Place the contents below in the file.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "npm:build",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": { "kind": "build", "isDefault": true },
            "command": "/home/gt/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm run build"
        }
    ]
}
```

The group setting makes this task the default and a build-style task in VS Code. Thus, it enables it to be launched from `ctrl+shift+b`.

[VS Code JS Build Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_running-babel)

Answer (score 1):

I am using nvm and wrote a wrapper script that reads the node version from `.nvmrc`. This avoids hardcoding a specific node version in multiple places. The wrapper script is configured for all shell commands in `settings.json` using the `terminal.integrated.automationShell.<os>` setting.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ "$2" == nvm* ]]; then
    export NODE_VERSION=v$(cat .nvmrc)
    if [ -z "$NODE_VERSION" ]; then
        echo "$(pwd)/.nvmrc does not exist or is empty"
        exit 1
    fi
    CLEAN_CMD=$(echo $2 | sed -e 's/nvm/npm/g')

    /bin/bash -c "~/.nvm/nvm-exec $CLEAN_CMD"
else
    /bin/bash -c $@
fi
```

A task can then use the correct node version using the `nvm <command>` command:

```
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "nvm run compile",
        "label": "npm-compile",            
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
        "isBackground": false,  
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always"
        },
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
```

There is also a gist that provides a little bit more information: https://gist.github.com/fvclaus/540c08921ba884fef959053c4f974bfc

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by sourcing file where NVM is setup and then running npm commands.

Example:

```
"command": "source scripts/nvm && npm run develop",
```

```
# ./scripts/nvm

# This is for users who don't have a global Node.js installation but instead
# rely on NVM. This file is sourced when running build tasks in non-login
# shells.

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Alternatively you can source ~/.bash_profile (or any other file) here. We feel this is a better alternative than hardcoding nvm's npm path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not in the right directory.

> Try the below method.
>
> Open any ts/html file from any component the do the same
>   (Ctrl+Shift+B).
>
> Probably it will work, it's work for me.

Still you face the same problem please share the snapshot.

Comment: I think am in the right directory. I have my package.json and package-lock.json in that directory at the top level, alongside node_modules and the gulpfile.js

Answer (score 0):

Try **File -> Open Folder**, opening your npm project folder and run your build command from there. If that fails, you may need to update your tasks.json to look similar to

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "npm:build",
      "type": "shell",
      "group": { "isDefault": true,"kind": "build",  },
      "command": "npm run build"
    }
  ]
}
```